# Jquery overlapping effect issue

Tags: jquery

I am trying to listen to an element effects on overlapping elements. I only want the hover effect on itemB when I hover to element B. However, since element B is on top of element A, the hover effect on element A also shows up. Are there anyways to solve this? Thanks a lot.

my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/pP7h3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp8d/2

Work exactly like what you want. jQuery has mouseleave and mouseout events which fires only once.

You can use hover also but when you have many elements with in A & B each time you change mouse position form one element to other hover will fire. You don't need that to be fired unless mouse moves out of B.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 var overA = function(){
    $('#itemA').css('display','block');
};
  var outOfA = function(){
    $('#itemA').css('display','none');
};

  var overB = function(e){
    outOfA();
    $('#itemB').css('display','block');
    e.stopPropagation();
};

var outOfB = function(){
    overA();
    $('#itemB').css('display','none');
}

$('#a').mouseenter(overA).mouseleave(outOfA);

$('#b').mouseenter(overB).mouseleave(outOfB);

})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `event.stopPropagation()`: http://jsfiddle.net/rcdmk/pP7h3/1/

```
$('#b').hover(function(e){
    $('#itemB').css('display','block');
    e.stopPropagation(); // e is the event passed by jQuery to the function
},function(){
    $('#itemB').css('display','none');
})
```

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

> **Description:** Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

If you need, you have `stopImediatePropagation()` aswell:

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/

> **Description:** Keeps the rest of the handlers from being executed and prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree.
>
> In addition to keeping any additional handlers on an element from being executed, this method also stops the bubbling by implicitly calling event.stopPropagation().

Comment: Thanks. But it only works if I hover to div B first. If I hover to div A then div B. ItemA won't disappear....:( +1 though